# How to join table in sql without removing data from table1

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, oracle10g

For every person in column D with number in it.

I need to find person's last name from 2nd table.

```
select
    a.TIME_STAMP,
    a.RDATE,
    a.TYPE,
    a.PERSON
from table1 a
```

[image: a pic]

table2 has person's lastname and field is called last

I tried

```
select
    a.TIME_STAMP,
    a.RDATE,
    a.TYPE,
    a.PERSON,
    b.last,
from table1 a, table b 
where a.PERSON = b.PERSON
```

and it outputs following by removing ABC_CHANGE from the result

[image: b pic]

How can I fix query so it won't remove ABC_CHANGE.

I am doing this in crystal report just for extra information but it does same in SQLPlus.

Comment: You need to use a left join, not a cross-join

Comment: @lc. The WHERE clause actually makes it an INNER JOIN, rather than a CROSS JOIN. You're correct about needing to use a LEFT JOIN though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yeah, I think I jumped the gun. I was thinking "well you need both `WHERE a.PERSON = b.PERSON` and `WHERE b.PERSON IS NULL` but this only makes sense in a left join, blah blah."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all rows in table A, even if there isn't a match in table B, you need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
select
    a.TIME_STAMP,
    a.RDATE,
    a.TYPE,
    a.PERSON,
    b.last,
from table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table b ON a.PERSON = b.PERSON
```

Comment: A left outer join will indeed preserve the rows where there is no corresponding row in the right table (table B), however it does not seem to respond to his requirement, which is to find the person's name in the second table.  Those rows do not have any matching name in the second table.

Comment: @EricB. The question says "How can I fix query so it won't remove ABC_CHANGE." so I answered that part. He'll get the last name of the person when there is a match, and get rows without a last name when there isn't a match. That's the best he can hope for.

Comment: Agreed.  However I understand the question to mean that he wants ABC_CHANGE in a row with the person's last name, which is impossible since there is no matching join criteria for person for that row.

Comment: @EricB. From the first part of the question: "For every person in column D with number in it. I need to find person's last name from 2nd table." I assumed that wasn't what they meant. Seems like they're more than happy to have no last name if there's nothing in column D.

Comment: Thanks that worked, in column D, it will only have 1 type of Data. it will only have number if not it will be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all the rows which contain ABC_CHANGE in table1 do not have any PERSON value.  Consequently, when you use a cross- join, those rows are skipped.  So it isn't "removing" ABC_CHANGE.  It is giving you the correct results.  If you want the rows still displayed (even though they do not match anything in the second table), you need to use a left join; this will show nulls for any non-matching columns in the second table.

```
select
    a.TIME_STAMP,
    a.RDATE,
    a.TYPE,
    a.PERSON,
    b.last,
from table1 a left join table b 
on a.PERSON = b.PERSON
```

However, this does not really match my understanding of your needs/requirements.

Comment: there is no difference between the two answers - the keyword `OUTER` in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

or skip the outer join altogether and put the translation of last name in the select list as follows:

```
SELECT     a.TIME_STAMP
,     a.RDATE
,     a.TYPE
,     a.PERSON
,     (Select b.last from b where b.person = a.person) last
FROM a
;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    a.TIME_STAMP,
    a.RDATE,
    a.TYPE,
    a.PERSON,
    b.last,
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.PERSON=b.PERSON
WHERE a.PERSON IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: -1 the addition of `a.PERSON IS NOT NULL` completely defeats the purpose.